# Openstack horizon UI customizations

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I have OpenStack Juno running and for our requirements I am trying to 'hide' the entire Network Panel under Project. For example it has

```
Project
  **Network**
    Routers
    Networks
```

We need to hide the Panel Network. I have reviewed the customization documentation on openstack, and have been trying to apply the overrides.py. From the documentation I am able to do the following.

```
projects_dashboard = horizon.get_dashboard("project")
volumes_panel = projects_dashboard.get_panel("volumes")
images_panel = projects_dashboard.get_panel("images")
as_panel =  projects_dashboard.get_panel("access_and_security")

permissions = list(getattr(volumes_panel, 'permissions', []))
permissions.append('openstack.roles.admin')
volumes_panel.permissions = tuple(permissions)
```

this works fine. But I can not find the correct object to work with that represents the Network panel. This is my first dive into Openstack and I'll post any other information needed.

Answer (score 0):

In file  /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/dashboard.py,

commenting out NetworkPanels in the Project class definition does the trick for me.

```
class Project(horizon.Dashboard):
    name = _("Project")
    slug = "project"
    panels = (
        BasePanels,
    #    NetworkPanels,
        ObjectStorePanels,
        OrchestrationPanels,
        DatabasePanels,)
    default_panel = 'overview'
    supports_tenants = True
```